# Nlog не сохраняет логи на microSD

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nlog

На устройстве запускаю приложение, которое при старте должно записывать соответствующие сообщение в блокнот.  Однако логирования не происходит, файл не создается. Xamarin forms.

код в MainActivity:

```
    public ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Logger.Trace("Start!");
        ....
    }
```

Кофигурация Nlog.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
  <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
        fileName="/mnt/sdcard/smsservice/logfile.txt"
        archiveFileName="/mnt/sdcard/smsservice/log.txt"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        concurrentWrites="true"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        maxArchiveFiles="7"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyMMdd" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
  <logger name="*" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

С чем может быть связана эта проблема? Тестирую через Visual Studio 2015, драйвер устройства установлен.

Comment: Во первых, вы точно уверены, что путь до внешнего хранилища именно такой (вот к примеру какие они [встречались](https://gist.github.com/PauloLuan/4bcecc086095bce28e22#gistcomment-1297081)).? Путь вроде храниться тут `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory`. Во вторых, а имеете ли вы права на [запись](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru)?